# Elegant solution to deserialize field that can be list or object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I'm integrating with an API that responses with the follwing format:

```
{
    status: {
        status: 200,
        response_code: "SUCCESS",
        // ...
    },
    data: {
        //...
    }
}
```

The `data` part can be an object or list of objects.
To work with it I have created a nice generic class:

```
data class ApiResponseDTO<T> (

        @JsonProperty("status")
        val status: ResponseStatusDTO,

        @JsonProperty("data")
        val dataAny: T?
)
```

Then I could use it in my Feign Client as:

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
fun foo(): ApiResponse<SomeDataObject>

@GetMapping("/bar")
fun bar(): ApiResponse<List<SomeDataObject>>
```

Everything was working fine until I found an inconsistency in this API. When the requested endpoint doesn't return anything, it always return an empty array `[]`.
So a request that returns something like:

```
// Foo response
{
    status: {
        // ...
    },
    data: {
        foo: "bar"
    }
}
```

Returns the following if it has no data to show:

```
// Foo response
{
    status: {
        // ...
    },
    data: []
}
```

This of course breaks my serialization/deserialization because I was always expecting a return of `ApiResponse<FooObject>` and suddenly I get a `ApiResponse<List<FooObject>>`

I'm looking for an elegant way to work around this scenario.
I was thinking something like:

```
data class ApiResponseDTO<T> (

        @JsonProperty("status")
        val status: ResponseStatusDTO,

        @JsonSetter("data")
        val dataJson: JsonNode
) {
        @get:JsonGetter("data")
        val data: T?
                get() {
                        val om = ObjectMapper()
                        return // Check wheter the JsonNode is an empty array and my T is not a Collection type and return null
                        // Otherwise, use ObjectMapper to deserialize the dataJson into my T object
                }
}
```

Problem is I cannot get `T` type at runtime because of the erasing, so I can't find a way to deserialize it with `ObjectMapper`.

I also tried writing a custom `StdDeserializer` for the `data` field, but couldn't find a way to make it work with generics :s

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` annotation for that field, and always accept input as array

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool that is an elegant way indeed n_n

Comment: happy to help always